# How to create button with text and image in bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

[image: Flag button]

Hi Friends,

I am working project in bootstrap. Can anyone please tell me how to create button with text and image as i shown in the image.

Thanks in advance

Regards,
Sathish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need Bootstrap to do this.

Simple example:

```css
.flag {
  border-right: 1px #000 solid;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<button>
  <span class="flag">flag</span>
  My button
</button>
```

Create your style with this structure.
**span.flag** is only a example to your flag image/icon.

Comment: Thanks Rafael. i try it.